# Excel: Find and replace first row of and excel sheet

Tags: excel, replace, find, vba

I want a code to find and replace all cells in a first row of an excel sheet. I have this following code by searching google.

```
Sub FindReplace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("Fname", "Lname", "Phone")
rplcList = Array("First Name", "Last Name", "Mobile")

For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Rows(1).Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
               LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
               SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht
Next x

End Sub
```

This works fine. but we should mention the find and replace list in the code itself. How to make it to take input from the user end instead of manually giving it in the code. Input as text or file would be good.

Comment: To take input from user use `Inputbox` method.

Comment: can please give me a piece of code. I do not know how to code and I'm sure I'll end up in huge error...

Comment: I have a big list to replace. will the `Inputbox` support multiple iterations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fndList = Split(Application.InputBox("List the values to be searched for in the following format: " & vbCrLf & "val1, val2, val3, ...", Type:=2), ",") '<--| this returns an array of 'String's
rplcList = Split(Application.InputBox("List the values to be replaced in the following format: " & vbCrLf & "val1, val2, val3, ...", Type:=2), ",") '<--| this returns an array of 'String's

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        sht.Rows(1).Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next x
Next sht
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the code. but it is only updating my A1 cell. I'm giving input Fname, Lname, Phone and Fisrtname, Lastname, Mobile. am I doing any mistake here?

Comment: I still get the same result. Only "A1" cell is getting updated.

Comment: It's because of the leading _spaces_: either you change the input format from `"val1, val2, val3, ..."` to `"val1,val2,val3, ..."` (i.e. you ask the user not to type a _space_ after each delimiting comma) or you `Trim()` both `fndList(x)` and `rplcList(x)` (i.e. `sht.Rows(1).Replace What:=Trim(fndList(x)), Replacement:=Trim(rplcList(x)), _...`

Comment: Your code without _space_ works for fine. Trim() function give me `Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`

Comment: it works for me: you have to substitute the final `...` with what was already in the code

Comment: i replaced `Trim` with `vba.trim`. Now it works fine. Thank You very much sir.